"Decorate" return type in C# child classes
Objective: Serialize data from a class, with the base class taking care of its properties and child classes taking care only of the "new" properties added.
Disclaimer: I come from TypeScript and it's been too long from my C/C++/Java times ;)
My idea in TS would be like this:
interface ParentData {
  foo: string;
}

class Parent {
  foo: string;

  public getSerializableData(): ParentData {
    // Parent only knows about foo, serializes it:
    return { foo: this.foo };
  }
}

interface ChildData extends ParentData {
  foo: string;
}

class Child extends Parent {
  bar: string;

  public getSerializableData(): ParentData {
    // child doesn't need to know how parent's data is serialized,
    // so just "extends" the data from the parent, with its own:
    const data = super.getSerializableData() as ChildData;
    data.foo = this.foo;
    return foo;

    // or this version if you prefer maintaining types without casting:
    const data = super.getSerializableData();
    return {
      ...data,
      foo: this.foo,
    };
  }
}

const instance: Parent = new Child();
const serialized = JSON.stringify(instance.getSerializableData());

So... in C# I don't really fancy the idea of having to re-create/copy the whole object in the children like...
// omitting the Parent class...

public class Child : Parent
{
  public class Data : Parent.Data
  {
    string bar;
  }

  private string bar;

  public override Parent.Data GetSerializableData()
  {
    var data = base.GetSerializableData();
    return new Child.Data() {
      foo = data.foo,
      bar = data.bar,
    };
  }
}

Also, I don't like the idea of just creating the Serializable data as a Dictionary<string, object>... (but it would be just a question of adding extra keys... and the return type would be always the same)
And in any case, I feel like it would break due to casting management and being other type of object even if I use the TypeNameHandling.Auto setting
using Newtonsoft.Json;

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
  TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
};
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
  new Child().GetSerializableData(),
  settings
);

So, coming for ideas that instruct me in the C# world :)

Could you use Newtonsoft's [JsonProperty] for serializable things and [JsonIgnore] for non-serializable things, avoiding the whole separate Data class?

@ipodtouch0218 not that easy, as the real data require of custom processing to avoid loops, etc. and even if it were possible, it would only solve the problem of serialization, not the general question itself about design patterns in C#

Since you can't assign arbitrary properties, you'll have to create the Data instance at the child and pass that upwards through the chain of ancestors:
public class Parent
{
  public class Data {
    public string foo;  
  }

  private string foo;

  public virtual Data GetSerializableData(Data data = null) {
    data ??= new Data();
    data.foo = foo;
    return data;
  }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
  public new class Data : Parent.Data
  {
    public string bar;
  }

  private string bar;

  public override Parent.Data GetSerializableData(Parent.Data data = null)
  {
    data ??= new Child.Data();
    base.GetSerializableData(data);

    Child.Data childData = (Child.Data) data;
    childData.bar = bar;
    return childData;
  }
}

public class Grandchild : Child
{
  public new class Data : Child.Data
  {
    public string baz;
  }

  private string baz;

  public override Parent.Data GetSerializableData(Parent.Data data = null)
  {
    data ??= new Grandchild.Data();
    base.GetSerializableData(data);

    Grandchild.Data grandchildData = (Grandchild.Data) data;
    grandchildData.baz = baz;
    return grandchildData;
  }
}

Since you're new to C#, here's some of the syntax sugar used:

??= creates and assigns only if the variable is null. Same as if (x == null) x = new Class();
GetSerializableData(Parent.data data = null) is a default parameter, it allows the caller to not specify the parameter and it'll default to null. This allows the public-facing API to use child.GetSerializableData(); instead of having to do child.GetSerializableData(new Child.Data()); or child.getSerializableData(null);
public new class Data : Parent.Data: the new keyword explicitly specifies that the hiding the Parent.Data name is intentional to silence a warning


Nice. This approach worked just fine. I tried a lot of them (i.e. creating custom serializers/deserializers is complex because each level of inheritance might write in the middle so... possible but hard to read and maintain...) This was actually very simple I don't know how I didn't thought by myself (well, because it goes upstream, passing the created base object from the child to the parent). Interesting. Thanks!
